# Can you create a mobile website using Ruby on Rails that has access to phone location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, mobile

I am in the beginning stages of planning a mobile website that has access to a phone's location.

I have no experience with mobile development, my experience lies with Ruby on Rails. My question is whether or not it I can build this type of website using Ruby on Rails. Is it possible on a mobile website to grab a user's location?

Comment: Depends. Read mobile os api docs.

Comment: Use IP geolocation serverside; or HTML5 geolocation clientside. Ruby on Rails is irrelevant. (Note: clientside geolocation works better, but requires user's consent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this lib http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/.  It should help getting a location from your mobile device.